# How to add icon on top of bootstrap navbar menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, navbar

I'm gonna add my own icons **on top** of each section in menubar, for example: Home icon on top of home, or Car icon on top of Cars, and etc, now it's showing in **left side**
I tried all suggested ways but icons don't show on top of menu. how can I solve it?
Here is my code:

```css
.navbar-wrapper2{min-height:0px; background:white; border-bottom:0px solid #cccccc; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13); padding-bottom:0px;}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.navbar-wrapper2{min-height:110px; background:white; border-bottom:0px solid #cccccc; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13); padding-bottom:0px;}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
          <!-- Navigation-->
          <div class="navbar-header go-right">
            <button data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://www.sothink.com/page/logo-design/images/company-logo10.jpg" alt="" class="moto"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right go-left">
              <li class="dropdown active go-right">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href=""> Home </a>
              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="m/hotels" class="" target="_self">
                  <!--<i class='fa fa-building'></i>--> Hotels                     </a>
                              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="/tours" class="" target="_self">
                  <!--<i class='fa fa-briefcase'></i>--> Tours                      </a>
                              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="/cars" class="" target="_self">
                  <!--<i class='fa fa-car'></i>--> Cars                       </a>
                              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="/offers" class="" target="_self">
                  <!--<i class='fa fa-gift'></i>--> Offers                     </a>
                              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="/blog" class="" target="_self">
                  <!--<i class='fa fa-building'></i>--> Blog                       </a>
                              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="/flightsd" class="" target="_self">
                  <!--<i class='fa fa-building'></i>--> Flights                    </a>
                              </li>
                            <li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="/contact-us" class="" target="">
                  <!--<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt'></i>--> Contact                  </a>
                              </li>
                                          <form class="dropdown pull-right">
                <div class="styled-select">
                  <select onchange="change_currency(this.value)" class="selectx" style="margin-top:10px;font-weight: 100;height: 2.3em;" name="currency" id="currency">
                                        <option value="1" selected="">US Dollar</option>
                                        <option value="3">GB Pound</option>
                                        <option value="9">SR Saudi</option>
                                      </select>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </form>
                                          <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                <a style="border-bottom: 0px;" href="javascript: void();" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="/uploads/images/language/en.png" alt="English" height="14" width="21"> English </a>
                <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/en" data-langname="English" id="en" class="changelang"><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/282/flags/48/united_states_of_america_usa.png" alt="" height="14" width="21">  English</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/ru" data-langname="Russia" id="ru" class="changelang"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gosquared/flag/64/Russia-icon.png" alt="" height="14" width="21">  Russia</a></li>
                                  </ul>
              </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-submenu">My Account <b class="lightcaret mt-2"></b></a>
                <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="/login">  Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/register">  Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                          </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I highly appreciate it and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used `inline element`, so they are showed beside of each. 
you should use `block elements` to take element down. 
for example add `<p>` tag to Hotels

```
<li class="go-right  ">
                <a href="m/hotels" class="" target="_self">
                  <i class='fa fa-building'></i><p>Hotels</p>                     </a>
                              </li>
```

and if you want icons go center of buttons:
add `text-align:center;` to the parent class of  `font-awesome <i> tags`.
please see this link and notice to `editfromStack` :
http://jsbin.com/kewahadike/edit?output

or you can add `<span>` to words like `hotel` and use `span{display:block;}` on stylesheet

please see this link:
http://jsbin.com/kumuvenanu/edit?html,output

Comment: No, Currently icons are beside of each menu title, so I'm gonna move them to up of menu items, like up of home, up of cars. <p> isn't right way. I'm looking for css to change it in up of each title

Comment: when you use bare word after <i> tag. how does css can find what do you want?
infact css know elements. not bare element.
you add a <p> tag. but you say to css this is an element.

Comment: try this,
<a href="m/hotels" class="editfromStack" target="_self">
                  <span class='fa fa-building'></span><span>Hotels</span>    

via 

span{
 display:block;
}

Comment: please, see the answer again.i add another approach.

Comment: Yes Now it's on top, but text-align:center; doesn't work.

Comment: but, it is worked on jsbin.
please give me a link of your code like me on jsbin that i can see whats wrong.